# Stripe API throwing error when trying to delete a card

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I'm trying to delete a card from Stripe using the ruby library but I am running in to the following error.

```
undefined method `delete' for Stripe::Customer:Class
```

Here is the line in my code that is causing the error

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.delete(@user.stripe_id)
```

There doesn't seem to be a delete method on the Customer class but the docs say there is.

Here is the section of the Stripe documentation that deals with deleting cards.
https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#delete_card

As you can see my code is identical to the line in the docs other than where the customer id is coming from.

Also, I did notice an error in the documentation in which,

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.delete({CARD_ID})
```

Should be,

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.delete({CUSTOMER_ID})
```

I've tried using the card id as well just to be sure and it generates the same error.

If anyone has any ideas, they would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I have been using stripe up until this point just fine with other methods such as `Stripe::Customer.retrieve()` working just fine.

EDIT 2: I'm using gem version 1.8.4 which seems to be the latest release.

Comment: Yeah, Stripe still doesn't let a customer [delete its card number](https://support.stripe.com/questions/can-i-delete-a-customer-s-card-from-my-stripe-account), I think it's unacceptable.

Comment: Actually it might be possible, see this [blog post](https://stripe.com/blog/multiple-cards) and the [relevant API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#delete_card). Though, the websites using Stripe I have encountered so far don't care to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There seem to be two errors in the docs, have you tried this instead:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve({CUSTOMER_ID})
customer.cards.retrieve({CARD_ID}).delete()
```

Comment: I'm getting a `*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method 'delete' for #<Stripe::ListObject:0x007fb62e33afb8>` when trying to delete cards

Comment: Fix: `card = customer.cards.retrieve({CARD_ID})`; `card.delete`

Comment: Thanks guys! I used the version in the updated docs and it worked!

Comment: It's now `card = customer.sources.retrieve({CARD_ID})`